# SQL Server query help needed for joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have these three tables in SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientInfo]
(
    [ClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ClientAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientID)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientInsuranceInfo]
(
    [InsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NULL,
    [InsTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [ActiveDate] [date] NULL,
    [InsStatus] [bit] NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (InsID)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TypeInfo]
(
    [TypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TypeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TypeID)
)
```

Some sample data to execute the query

```
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Lionel Van Praag', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Bluey Wilkinson', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Jack Young', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Keith Campbell', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Tom Phillis', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Barry Smith', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')
insert into ClientInfo (ClientName, State, Country, Status) 
values ('Steve Baker', 'NSW', 'Australia', 'True')

insert into TypeInfo (TypeName) values ('CarInsurance')
insert into TypeInfo (TypeName) values ('MotorcycleInsurance')
insert into TypeInfo (TypeName) values ('HeavyVehicleInsurance')

insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus)
values ('1', '1', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('1', '2', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('2', '1', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('2', '2', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('2', '3', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('3', '1', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('4', '1', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('4', '3', '2000-01-11', 'True')
insert into ClientInsuranceInfo (ClientID, InsTypeID, ActiveDate, InsStatus) 
values ('5', '2', '2000-01-11', 'True')
```

I have written the following query which returns only those clients who have 'MotorcycleInsurance' type:

```
select distinct 
    ClientInfo.ClientID, ClientInfo.ClientName, TypeInfo.TypeName
from 
    ClientInfo 
left join 
    ClientInsuranceInfo on ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientInsuranceInfo.ClientID
left join 
    TypeInfo on ClientInsuranceInfo.InsTypeID = TypeInfo.TypeID 
             and TypeInfo.TypeID = 2
where 
    typeinfo.TypeName is not null
```

But I want to do the following things

- I want to return all clients who have 'MotorcycleInsurance' along with rest of clients who do not have 'MotorcycleInsurance' as well.
- `TypeName` will be returned as NULL who do not have 'MotorcycleInsurance'
- `ClientID` have to be unique in the result set.
- Do not want to use `UNION` / `UNION ALL`.

How can I do this?

My required answer will be as follow

[image]

Comment: With a preamble longer than the US Constitution, you should take a moment to show us _exactly_ the output you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select a.ClientID, a.ClientName, a.TypeName
from 
(
select distinct ClientInfo.ClientID, ClientInfo.ClientName, TypeInfo.TypeName, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ClientInfo.ClientID order by case when TypeName is null then 1 else 0 end) as rn
from ClientInfo  
left join ClientInsuranceInfo on ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientInsuranceInfo.ClientID
left join TypeInfo on ClientInsuranceInfo.InsTypeID = TypeInfo.TypeID and TypeInfo.TypeID = 2
) a
where rn = 1
```

Edit: Updated ordering by `case` statement in `Row_Number` :)

Comment: this been very help full. But 'ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ClientInfo.ClientID order by case when TypeName is null then 1 else 0 end) as rn' can I put multiple column condition as like TypeName? any suggestion?

Comment: 'ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ClientInfo.ClientID order by case when TypeName is null then 1 else 0 end) as rn' why you put TypeName is null then 1 else 0 and in where condition rn = 1

Comment: this is just my way of defining the ordering - non null values first (0) and then null values will get value of 1  for ascending ordering :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your `where` clause and change join condition slightly

```
select distinct ClientInfo.ClientID, ClientInfo.ClientName, TypeInfo.TypeName
from ClientInfo 
left join ClientInsuranceInfo 
         on ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientInsuranceInfo.ClientID 
            and ClientInsuranceInfo.InsTypeID = 2 
left join TypeInfo on ClientInsuranceInfo.InsTypeID = TypeInfo.TypeID
```

Comment: If I remove 'where' clause then some ClientID will be return multiple times. Which client has other insurance type along with 'MotorcycleInsurance ' type, they will be returned multiple times. But I require unique clientID to return.

Comment: You need to filter out the other types while joining client tables as you dont need them. So, when you come down to TypeInfo, you will avoid duplicates. Alternatively, you can change the order of joins. which will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CI.ClientID, CI.ClientName, TI.TypeName
FROM dbo.ClientInfo AS CI
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ClientID, InsTypeID
           FROM dbo.ClientInsuranceInfo
           WHERE InsTypeID = 2 
           GROUP BY ClientID, InsTypeID ) AS CII ON CI.ClientID = CII.ClientID
LEFT JOIN dbo.TypeInfo AS TI  ON CII.InsTypeID = TI.TypeID;
```